# Is this hadith sahih? "Whoever prays 4 raka'at (units) of Duha prayer, then Allah will suffice him for it (i.e., his needs) until the evening."

Tags: hadith

Whoever prays four raka'at (units) of Duha prayer, then Allah will suffice him for it (i.e., his needs) until the evening."

Is this sahih or hasan?

Comment: https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:475 | https://sunnah.com/abudawud:1289

Comment: I don't know of any Hadith quoting Doha prayer explicitly in such a context. Due to the unclear wording "begin of the day" scholars differ between two explanations either it is fajr Sunnah and Sobh (fair fard) as in Arabic the begin of the day is at fajr or it is Doha based on an interpretation that the day starts with sunrise how er for Doha no fix amount of taka's was defined and I don't know of any specific recommendation for praying it in 4 raka't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In internet i found this:

Uqbah ibn ‘Amir reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Verily, Allah Almighty says: O son of Adam, suffice Me with four cycles of prayer at the beginning of the morning and by them I will suffice you for the rest of your day.”

Source: Musnad Aḥmad 17390

Grade: Sahih (authentic) according to Al-Arna’ut

عَنْ عُقْبَةَ بْنِ عَامِرٍ الْجُهَنِيِّ أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ قَالَ إِنَّ اللهَ يَقُولُ يَا ابْنَ آدَمَ اكْفِنِي أَوَّلَ النَّهَارِ بِأَرْبَعِ رَكَعَاتٍ أَكْفِكَ بِهِنَّ آخِرَ يَوْمِكَ

17390 مسند أحمد

28/613 المحدث شعيب الأرناؤوط خلاصة حكم المحدث صحيح في تخريج المسند